# Run multiple gui programs from terminal without disowning them

Tags: command-line, bash, process

I made a very simple (but useful for me) bash script. All it does is just opening some applications that I was opening manually. Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
netbeans &
mysql-workbench &
opera &
chromium-browser &
```

Now when I close the terminal the applications opened by the script keep running. Which is normal, that is what the "&" is there for.

My question is: Is there a way to still run those applications automatically but also close them automatically? If they were still attached to the terminal they would close, but when I remove the ampersand it only runs the first application.

Thanks

Comment: killall <app-name> is what you mean to auto kill them ? auto kill them when ? at a specific time ? when a arguement is true like cpu usage bigger then a X% ? specify when you want to auto-kill them and make a loop with "while" or "if" command . don't forget to add a sleep timer for the cpu to rest a bit and don't loop like crazy 24/7.

Comment: @PavlosTheodorou I think they want closing the terminal to also close the multiple applications started therein.

Comment: @Chai T.Rex , closing the terminal kills them all. i don't think he means that. Maybe he means to seperate the app using nohup, for example: $nohup firefox, either use disown for example: $firefox &; disown. And then close the apps seperately. Or he wants to use the command killall <app name> We wait from Karim to explain what he means to auto close the apps.

Comment: @PavlosTheodorou with `&` after a GUI program, the GUI program will start, but closing the terminal won't close the GUI program.

Comment: _"Now when I close the terminal the applications opened by the script keep running. Which is normal, that is what the "&" is there for."_ - No, that is not what `&` is for. Using `&` has no bearing on whether or not the applications quit when you close the terminal. Closing the terminal causes the application to get SIGHUP. If the application doesn't terminate it is because it purposefully ignores that signal. Not because you used `&`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These two functions can be used from your `.bashrc` file to launch and close them, simply call them with `lapp` and `kapp`:

```
lapp(){
     netbeans &
     mysql-workbench &
     opera &
     chromium-browser &
}

kapp() {
    pkill 'netbeans|mysql-workbench|opera|chromium-browser'
}

#Or

kapp() {
    killall 'netbeans|mysql-workbench|opera|chromium-browser'
}
```

Information:

- remember to run `source .bashrc` after adding these functions

<sup>(source: [`man pkill`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/pkill.1.html))</sup>

Comment: sorry for asking this, but it's my first time i read about adding commands to .bashrc. This way the apps open without owning the terminal right ? so the disown or nohup are not necessary ? we run lapp , close terminal if we want and then run kapp and close them ?

Comment: nvm i never tried opening apps from terminal so.... nub question from me. already answered in comments. opening with & it doesn't own the terminal.

Comment: I don't like this because any other instances of these applications would be killed as well. Admittedly some of these might be single-instance applications but you wouldn't want an instance you had open prior to opening your terminal to be killed.

Comment: @Muzer, the OP said he wants to close what he had opened so what other instance are you talking about?

Comment: @Gergoe let's say OP already had an instance of netbeans running. Then when they opened their terminal a second instance would be opened. When they later closed their terminal *both* copies of netbeans would be closed!

Comment: That is not what the OP suggested. My answer is not to assume what the OP would do but to offer a potential solution to what the OP asked. OP said I want to 1) open some apps, 2) close those apps... I believe that was what OP wanted. If OP wants something different then that's a new question  all together...

Comment: @Mazur, read a `question --> understand it --> proffer solution --> bonus other theories` now this your saying is a side note IMO...

Comment: @George,  you answered exactly what I asked for. The only thing is that killall -e chromium-browser for example does not work for me. However pkill -f appname works like a charm. Do you know why? If you are fine with pkill -f please update your answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @KarimMtl, I have updated the answer as requested. For the reason you asked, `pkill -f` looks for say `chromium, chromium-browser, etc`, while `killall -e` looks for exact match `chromium-browser` and if it doesn't see it nothing happens. Perhaps that process isn't actually called `chromium-browser` as specified in the terminal command...

Comment: Is there a reason to use `-f`? You're trying to match executable names here and `-f` is only useful to match other program arguments in addition to the executable name.

Comment: Your right @DavidFoerster, since OP isn't parsing any arguments then there's no need for it. I will update.

Comment: @DavidFoerster and an `-e` option would be useful to match what was originally run in the terminal.

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to source the script so that these commands are executed in your current shell, instead of in the forked-off shell started for the script:

```
. ./foo.sh
```

Then, these background processes will be part of your shell's job control.

It might be easier to use a function. In your bashrc, for example, add:

```
foo () {
    netbeans &
    mysql-workbench &
    opera &
    chromium-browser &
}
```

Then, when you run `foo` from bash, it will run the commands in your current shell.

Comment: oh , nice one , i didn't know i can do that. don't delete those lines when you edit the answer later (if you edit) to fit the auto close too.